# Curated list of politician's social media (Twitter)

Tags: data-request, social-media, politics

I found this great list from 2017 for all the Twitter handles for the 100 US Senators and 428 of the US members of the House.

https://gwu-libraries.github.io/sfm-ui/posts/2017-05-23-congress-seed-list

- 115th Congress: [House](https://gwu-libraries.github.io/sfm-ui/resources/115th-Congress-House-seeds.csv)
- 115th Congress: [Senate](https://gwu-libraries.github.io/sfm-ui/resources/115th-Congress-Senate-seeds.csv)

I am looking for similar lists, or meta-lists, and for countries, states, regions, etc. The more curated (updated, up-to-date), the better. Could be Twitter or other social media (Facebook, Instagram, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Global**

- [@twiplomacy's world leaders list is a start](https://twitter.com/twiplomacy/lists/world-leaders/members?lang=en) but more importantly, they have a number of curated lists.
- [Every Politician](http://everypolitician.org/) has social links for politicians.
- [List of current heads of state and government/twitter-list - Archiveteam](https://www.archiveteam.org/index.php?title=List_of_current_heads_of_state_and_government/twitter-list)

**North America**

- [Politwoops US](https://projects.propublica.org/politwoops/)
- [Politwitter Lists (Canadian Gov)](http://politwitter.ca/page/twitter-lists)
- [US Senator Twitter Accounts, 115th Congress (Historical)](https://www.socialseer.com/resources/us-senator-twitter-accounts/)

**Europe**

- [EU](https://politwoops.eu/countries) certainly have lists that could be used.
- [Switzerland](http://twitterpolitiker.ch/fraktionen.html)

**Australia**

- [Parliament of New South Wales Twitter Links](https://www.parliament.nsw.gov.au/about/Pages/Twitter-Links.aspx)

---

*Notes:*

- I can't find anything about open civic data, but I know they have curated lists for USA and Canada.